# Django error: multiple default values for specified column "id"

Tags: django, django-models, docker-compose

I'm working with a project with docker-compose, where I have a *postgre container*.

When I run:

```
docker-compose -f dev.yml run django python manage.py migrate
```

I get the error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "scrapy_scrapy"
```

That is happening before I made some changes to my *models.py* file. But now the file is correct and should be working. This is the content of the *models.py* file:

```
from django.db import models
import django

# Create your models here.
class Scrapy(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    projecte = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    estat_last_check = models.CharField(max_length=700, default="", blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, blank=True)

    app_label = ''
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.projecte + " - " + self.user

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'scrapy'
```

As you can see, no *id* filed is defined anymore, so, why is complaining about that field?

I've done my research and tried some possible solutions, but no luck. I've already tried deleting the full Docker container and creating it again, or trying to delete the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is likely caused by a problem in a migration file in `scrapy/migrations`. Could you update your question with the contents of the latest migration file?

Comment: My guess is also migrations. You mentioned that you tried deleting your database, so I assume you are early in your project development and don't mind losing your test data. If that is the case, you can try deleting all migrations and running `makemigrations` again.

Comment: Deleting scrapy/migrations folder seems to have solved the issue, thanks!